# How can a avoid "typedef void * sql_context" being declared in C code generated through Pro C

Tags: c, oracle, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

I have a header file a.h

## a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
typedef void* sql_context; 
/other function and struct declarations.. 
#endif
```

and have a Proc C file.

## db.pc

```
#include <a.h>
// other code
```

when I compile db.pc using proc to generate db.c file, it declares `typedef void* sql_context;` in db.c, and it also include a.h.

## db.c

```
/* Thread Safety */
typedef void * sql_context;
typedef void * SQL_CONTEXT;

#include <a.h>
//other code
```

Now when I compile db.c, I get the following error:

> a.h:2: error: redefinition of typedef ‘sql_context’
>
> db.c:3: note: previous declaration of ‘sql_context’ was here

Is there a way or flag which I can use to avoid automatic declaration of `sql_context`? How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Why does `a.h` need to have this typedef in it? Is it a file whose contents you control?

Comment: because it is from a different module, and that too use this typedef.

Comment: Could that module get the typedef from a different header?